# Could use assistance interpreting a crash dump

Tags: windows-10, crash, bsod, sleep

I have an issue where my computer seems to crash when going into sleep mode, and also randomly reboot whilst already in sleep mode.

Consequently I've had to stop using sleep mode whilst I try to understand what's wrong.

I installed Windows Debugging Tool and tried to interpret the .dmp files, and messed around with some symbols, but no luck.

This only seems to have started happening recently, I'd say within the last 2 weeks.

Could anyone help me interpret these crash dumps? http://we.tl/T0QOCjwl6t I would be eternally grateful

Is there a step-by-step guide anywhere to debugging this, or does it really require a lot of pre-requisite knowledge?

**Update 13th October 2015**

An Intel exmployee in [answers.microsoft.com](http://example.com) posted on 9th October 2015 regarding the ICCWDT.sys issue:

> You may be hitting a known issue in the Intel ICC clocking driver.  We
>   are trying to drive resolution to this internally
>
> There is a fixed ICC clocking Windows driver.  This driver is expected
>   to be integrated into the next release of Intel XTU.

This issue was caused by installing the Intel Extreme Tuning Utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the crash seams to be caused by the driver ICCWDT.sys (Intel watchdog driver):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff8009f3f7838, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000008, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff8009f3f7838, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ICCWDT.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ICCWDT.sys

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
ICCWDT+7838
fffff800`9f3f7838 ??              ???

IP_IN_PAGED_CODE: 
ICCWDT+7838
fffff800`9f3f7838 ??              ???

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: cdd

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
ICCWDT+7838
fffff800`9f3f7838 ??              ???

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 ICCWDT
04 Wdf01000!FxTimer::TimerHandler
05 nt!KiRetireDpcList
06 nt!KxRetireDpcList
07 nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue
08 nt!KiDpcInterruptBypass
09 nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw
0a nt!RtlpGenericRandomPatternWorker
0b nt!RtlScrubMemory
0c nt!MiScrubPage
0d nt!MiScrubNode
0e nt!MiScrubMemoryWorker
0f nt!ExpWorkerThread
10 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
11 nt!KiStartSystemThread


FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:av_code_av_paged_ip_iccwdt!unknown_function


    Loaded symbol image file: ICCWDT.sys
    Image path: ICCWDT.sys
    Image name: ICCWDT.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Tue Apr 21 11:51:44 2015
```

Look if Intel offers a newer driver.

The confusing part is the paged Instruction pointer. Also run memtest86+ to detect memory issues.

Comment: Thanks Andre. Really appreciate you looking into this. The [http://bit.ly/1NF2jUi](top result) in google for ICCWDT.sys means I'm now 99% sure this is related to my installing the Intel® Extreme Tuning Utility (XTU) which must have put a new driver on my system. Having checked the install date, it's one day before the 6 relevant crash dumps. In the prior link, an Intel developer Toby Zimmerman mentioned on the 9th October 2015 (just a few days ago) that the fixed ICC clocking driver will be integrated into the next release of XTU

Comment: ok, nice to hear that Intel already knows about it and will fix it